# Hi Folks, I want to remove text written inside [ ] and need to replace with blank. Can someone hep me on this?

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
The code is [cid:7108371312034834373] used to create your new account.
```

and need to change the string to

```
The code is used to create your new account.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex here `/\[.*?\]\s*/` and [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to achieve the result

[image]

```js
const str =
  "The code is [cid:7108371312034834373] used to create your new account.";
const result = str.replace(/\[.*?\]\s*/, "");
console.log(result);
```